# Need help determining sample size for an AB test with two metrics

Tags: experiment-design, statistical-power, ab-test

I need to run an experiment with customer support agents who are rated on two metrics by the customer: average issue resolution rate (proportion of issues resolved) and average star rating (1-5). Whenever an agent gets a new issue, I plan to show a feature to the agent (or not show) 50% of the time at random.  Once the experiment is over, I would like to compare if there is:

- A difference in the average star rating between the issues where the
  feature was shown and the issues where the feature was not shown
- A difference in the resolution rate between the issues where the feature was shown and the issues where the feature was not shown

A couple of additional points:
i. The customer will not always leave a feedback. They on average leave feedback about resolution ~15% of the time and a star rating ~7% of the time.

ii. The star ratings are discrete (1-5 stars) with most of them being 5*, then a few 1* and the rest are very low. The average star rating is around 4.3 in the general population and resolution rate is around 55%

**Questions:**

1. What are the correct statistical tests for the above two comparisons?
2. How do I determine the sample size needed for determining an effect size of 0.1 in the star rating and 1% in the resolution rate with 90% power?

If someone could work the math out here, I'd be super delighted!

Answer (score 0):

1. Given you have two different responses you want to test for a difference in I would carry out two separate analyses:

i.To test for differences in the average star rating you could use an analysis of variance (ANOVA) test. I suggest ANOVA as the star rating is analogous to the Likert scale and the test is [robust enough to handle this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10459-010-9222-y).

ii.The resolution proportion is on a different scale though. In this case I would use a logistic regression model comparing the group shown the feature and those who weren't.

2. Sample size can be calculated with the bits you have supplied using [this calculator](https://www.stat.ubc.ca/~rollin/stats/ssize/n2.html).

*One additional point though - the fact that star rating is not obligatory will lead to an unknown bias in your data. I for one know I am more likely to leave feedback if my experience was really poor.

Comment: 1. What would I have to do to account for the fact that my star rating distribution is not normal when I do an ANOVA? (for example, create bootstrap samples, find average and use that distribution?)  
2. For the resolution rate, I just want to compare two binomial populations. Why do you suggest logistic regression for this? I do not have any predictors/features for this model.

As for the unknown bias, that's true and for this test, it's ok to have that. I understand that I am comparing a selective population of those who tend to leave feedback.

Comment: 1. If you have a large enough sample size you can rely on the central limit theorem for normality, as I assume this exercise isn't for prediction. If it is really bad there are transformations available but those are more of a last resort and dependent on what the issue is.

Comment: 2. Unless I have misunderstood your description, you do have a predictor - whether or not the agent was shown the feature. I prefer using logistic regression as I find that log-odds are easily interpreted and meaningful in this context. You can also use a test for difference in proportions which essentially does the same thing...  https://stattrek.com/hypothesis-test/difference-in-proportions.aspx